# CLLocation calling delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I'm attempting to get the users location upon switching to a specific view controller (FeedVC), this is the code I currently have:

FeedVC.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface FeedVC : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

FeedVC.m

```
@implementation FeedVC
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *location;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"did update locations");

    location = [locations lastObject];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%.2f", location.coordinate.latitude);
}
```

The method `locationManager: didUpdateLocations:` is not being called (as the NSLog is not shown up) I've followed all the documentation and other answers here but i cannot find the source of the problem, thanks!

Comment: Do you get prompted to allow the app to access location?  Are you running on the simulator or an actual device?

Comment: running on an actual device but I dont get promted.

Comment: Have you included the authorisation reason string in your info.plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call     `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` in viewDidLoad,
Call it in delegate method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

If you have not add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in your plist add it to describe why you want to use location service